# Child div height should be equal to its parent height when using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My requirement is that I want all the text class `div`'s should have same height or should occupy all the height of the parent `div` col.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the link for working code](https://jsfiddle.net/n4cggb8e/)

Comment: Do you mean the remaining height or all the height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `flex-direction: column` on parent div and `flex: 1` on child div.

Thus to your `.col` class add:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

And to `.text` class add :

```
flex:1;
```

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.text {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle to play with.](https://jsfiddle.net/n4cggb8e/1/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MihaiT No, they don't have equal height.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want the green text to cover the rest of the div. Well you need to set height of `.text` depending on the remaining space inside the div.

This is depending on the `img` height. In your example, images have 200px height.

If the heights are dynamic, you need to use something like javascript or jQuery . If not ( they have fixed heights ) you can use only CSS as in the example below, using `calc()` to calculate the height of the `.text` , subtracting the image height from the total height of the parent ( `.col` )

`100%` = height of `.col`
`200px` = height of `img`

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}
h3,p {
 margin-top:0
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  background: green;
 height:calc(100% - 200px)
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img" style="background:red;height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u help me by posting a jsfiddle link with the working css code only because the calc function is not working for me.

Comment: @Vamsiachyuta i do not need to post a fiddle. i posted a stack overflow snippet ( click on run code snippet ) and see it work . `calc()` is not supported in old IE versions . See here > http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc